# Web front-end for c++ code

Tags: php, c++, python, flask

I have c++ code that can be compiled under Linux, windows or Mac OS. The code compares two images. I would like to have its front end running on a browser and make available to the www.

I am familiar with hosting and dns and that is not the issue. what I can't seem to figure out is:

1. How do I invoke the script once the image is uploaded by users?
2. The results from the code needs to be displayed back to the browser. How can a callback be set up for this?

Is there a php solution? Or python (with flask)?

Comment: There is always a solution. But you have to start documenting and try something first. [php.net](http://www.php.net) should get you started if you want to do it by PHP.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either call the C++ application from PHP with [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and then return to browser whatever result is there. This is quick and not good idea. Better approach is to have a service/daemon in C++ running and taking tasks from queue (like RabbitMQ for example). This is scalable solution but requires more effort to implement.

Comment: RabbitMQ is too complex for this kind of usage, use Gearman (gearman.org) instead.

Comment: @0xBAADF00D arguments, please.

Comment: I use RabbitMQ at work and it's very big mailqueue and need lot of space to run (last version refuse to run if you don't have xx Gio of free space, even if server have 32 Gio of RAM). Gearnam run on small configuration and it ready to work more quickly than RabbitMQ. For this kind of usage, Gearman is more suitable, @dr_rk don;t need a full heavy mailqueue mechanism...

Comment: @0xBAADF00D that is not real argument but just anecdotical case. we have RabbitMQ working totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use CppCMS (http://cppcms.com/) ? CppCMS is a Free High Performance C++ Web Development Framework.

You can use it to handle HTTP request and file upload and easily integrate your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets, and start listening on some port from C++ program, then from PHP you can connect and send/receive data to/from your program.